# Switch between UIViewControllers in storyboard without Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIView (with identifierSplashScreen) which basically acts as a introduction view and displays a small animation. once the animation is completed i want the view to display a tabbar view which here in after will be the main view. no data of any kind is passed on from the first UIView to the second UIView(with identifier HomeScreen). I have seen most examples where the

```
secondViewController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
```

but this Pushes the view controller and a navigation bar with a back button appears which I dont want. Also I am never going to Return to the Splash Screen. it would be great if one of you could offer any help.

Iam a biggener and not a expert iOS programeer, so a simple code example will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing onto the navigation stack why not replace the stack?

eg.

`[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[svc] animated:NO]`

Comment: Thanks Mike! but i cant vote up your Answer as i dont have sufficinet reputaion yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a push segue and not have a navigation bar... Select your navigation controller and on the 4th tab on the right uncheck "Show Navigation Bar"

Comment: Hi Abdullah, Thanks for your suggestion yes yours too works when there exist a navigation controller. but in my app I dont use a explicit navigation controller anywhere. Any way may be my understandiang of navigation control and appdelegate defenitions are still very basic. if some one can suggest a good reading on this topic will be great.